# Can this be optimized? whois over a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, whois

This code in Python 3.4 works fine, but I am wondering how it can be made faster:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product
import whois

domains = list()
available_domains = list()

for c in map(''.join, product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2)):
    domains.append(c+'.at')

for dom in domains:
    domain = whois.query(dom)
    if domain == '':
        available_domains.append(domain)

print(available_domains)
```

Any input will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I would guess that `whois.query(dom)` is where your program spends most of the time (network call), and if that's true - what can you do to improve it?

Comment: whois is fetching data from the internet, commonly domain servers will deliberately throttle non-vital queries as a protection against dds type attacks. If you want to run it faster, you could bring all the websites you're whois-ing in-house onto your own private lan and optimise them for this query. (minor sarcasm)

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `async` module to execute the `whois.query` call asynchronously.

Comment: Code aside, lack of a WHOIS record does not necessarily imply that a domain is available. Also, you're going to get blocked by most WHOIS servers very quickly by running a lot of queries.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can get `domains` with comprehension:

```
domains = [''.join(i) + '.at' for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=2)]
```

And do the same with `available_domains`:

```
available_domains = [d for d in domains if whois.query(d)]
```

At least it is fewer lines :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `multiprocessing` module to map over the `domains` list, to be able to do the queries in parallel instead of serially. (By the way, since `whois.query()` is likely IO-bound, you can use the `multiprocessing.dummy` module to use threads instead of subprocesses.)